# Check if there are 1 or more specific files in a directory?

Tags: bash

I need to create script that goes like this:

```
if directory contains atleast one file (1 or more) that starts with 'naz'
    #do something
else (contains 0 files that start with 'naz')
    #do something else
```

My problem is that when I try

```
if [ -f naz* ]
```

I end up with

> bash: [: too many arguments

because there are more than 1 files that meet the criteria. I'm looking for a solution that would work with multiple files found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `[` test like this on multiple files.

Better do:

```
shopt -s nullglob
compgen -W naz* &>/dev/null
case $? in
    0) echo "only one file match" ;;
    1) echo "more than one file match" ;;
    2) echo "no file match" ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution might take a while to evaluate in a directory with a large number of files but is more succinct

```sh
if [ `find . -name "naz*" -type f -d 1 | wc -l` -ge 1 ]
```

If you want to travel to subdirectories you can do so by removing the `-d 1` part.